# How to get selected item value?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How to get ItemsControl display items selected Item textbox text value using MVVM pattern?

```
<ListBox Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModelSearchResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCategoryViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal" />
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryID}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like getting anything else from Views: bind it! Yes, `ItemsControl` has `SelectedItem` but `ItemsControl` itself doesn't have selection behavior. You should use something like `ListBox` instead.

Comment: now i have used listbox by using this code:
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCategoryViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" but binding not work proparly and goes to infinet loop.where i doing wrong?  @Snowbear

Comment: i am using this code in viewmodel. private CategoryViewModel _CategoryViewModel;
public CategoryViewModel SelectedCategoryViewModel
{
     get { return _CategoryViewModel; }
     set
     {
            if (_CategoryViewModel != value)
            {
                SelectedCategoryViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCategoryViewModel");
           }
      }
} @Snowbear

Comment: @Tulsi In your setter you're using setter again instead of backing field. Look for `SelectedCategoryViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind SelectedItem to a property and access the required values through that property.