# How to get value of textblock in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an `ItemControl` containing a list of elements.
I need to get the value of the `TextBlock` using MVVM.

This is my XAML code:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding IhmtEcosystemFilterList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Button  Margin="5" Height="80" Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Black" Command="{Binding CmdStatistiqueEcoSystem, ElementName={Binding Name}}">
               <StackPanel Width="150">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="17" Name="valueTxtBloc"  />
                   <Image x:Name="imgAvion" Source="/Resources/Images/avion.png"  Width="35"></Image>
               </StackPanel>
           </Button>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `{Binding CmdStatistiqueEcoSystem, ElementName={Binding Name}}` makes no sense and will of course not work. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, and why you think you need to access the TextBlock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get selected item value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766103/how-to-get-selected-item-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766798/how-to-bind-one-texblock-value-to-other-textblock-one-way-and-get-value-in-mvvm

Comment: The bottom line here: you get the value the same way you'd get any other value. From the view model via a binding. If you need to modify the view model data structure to create a property having the exact value you want, then do that (it's not clear whether you want the `Text` property from the `TextBox` or something else...if the `Text` property, then you already have a property that has that value: `Name`)